# IntelliJ shortcut for Thymeleaf parser-level comment blocks

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf you can use `parser-level comment blocks` that everything between `<!--/*` and `*/-->` will be removed by [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#thymeleaf-parser-level-comment-blocks).

```
<!--/* This code will be removed at Thymeleaf parsing time! */-->
```

Is there any way to define this type of comment and use a **shortcut** for it in the **IntelliJ IDEA**? I know we can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, but it generates *Standard HTML/XML comments* which are closed within `<!--` and `-->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It seems that there are no way to define a new comment style in IntelliJ IDEA. But I found a workaround by using the `Live Template` functionality.

You can create a live template for parser-level comment blocks and then invoke it. Follow the following path:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Live Templates` -> `HTML/XML` -> `ADD`

Copy and paste the following live-template to the Template text, and choose suitable abbreviation and description:

```
<!--/* $SELECTION$ */-->
```

[image]

There are two ways to use this live template

1. Type `PC` and then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, IntelliJ automatically creates a parser-level comment block.
2. Mark-up the desired codes or texts and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, and then from the shown pop-up menu you can select the parser-level comment block option.

[image]

Unfortunately you cannot set any Keymaps (shortcuts) for your Live-Templates.